# Have to press CTRL+f5 everytime to hit api. Without pressing it, cross origin request blocked error popped up

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cakephp

I am a beginner in angularJS.

I have tried to fetch data from API (CakePHP) in angularJS application. I have a menu named 'Fetch'. By just clicking 'Fetch' menu, it is redirected to 'fetchData' page but an error something stating, `'Network Error. Cross Origin Request Blocked'` popped in console and data do not load. But, if I press `Ctrl+f5` in the page 'fetchData', it works and data are successfully loaded on the page without having network issue.

The **.htaccess file** in cake php is something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]

    SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(my_url.com)$" origin_is=$0
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin,Authorization, authtoken, Accept"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</IfModule>
```

I don't know if the issue is of client side or of server side. Any suggestions will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code in that php file.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

cakephp 3.2 has [CorsBuilder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-2-migration-guide.html#corsbuilder-added) Here is my example of usage

```
        $this->response
                ->cors($this->request)
                ->allowOrigin(['http://localhost:8100'])
                ->allowCredentials(TRUE)
                ->allowMethods(['GET', 'POST'])
                ->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
                ->maxAge(300)
                ->build();
```